# I am trying to read an excel file using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It contains a method called OnChange which is reading the excel file.

This is my code for upload.js where I am trying to upload an excel file and read some of it's rows which contains specific keywords. I am not sure what's wrong in it?
I tried to run it but it is telling me Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob' and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
import React from "react";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

class Upload extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      excel_file: ""
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    var excelJsonObj = [];
  }

  onChange(e) {
    let files = e.target.files;
    console.warn("data files", files);
    const file = files.name;
    //var f = document.getElementById("file");
    //var input = f;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var fileData = e.target.result;
      var workbook = XLSX.read(fileData, { type: "binary" });
      const wsname = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = workbook.Sheets[wsname];
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv(ws, { header: 1 });
      console.log("Data>>>" + data);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(files);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Upload your excel file here</h2>
        <br />
        <span style={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
          <input
            type="file"
            name="file"
            onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}
            id="file"
          />
        </span>
        <br />
        <span style={{ marginTop: 2 }}>
          <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Submit" />
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Upload;

Expected Result:- It should read the excel file and display it on the browser.

Actual Result:-
1. TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
2. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Are you sure that your Excel file is valid though ?

Comment: Why do you use FileReader ?
Check the documentation for examples.

Comment: Yes the excel file is valid